# Which control to use

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I'm designing a data driven website, the content for which is displayed mostly with Repeater controls.

I'm not sure, though, how to present the content that won't be repeated (such as articles).
I had thought about using Labels and creating a DataSet when the page loads and populate the Labels on the page with columns from the DataSet...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create "single-record" data-bound control you can use either [FormView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.aspx) or [DetailsView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.aspx) controls

Comment: those the best ways to do it? It seems a little more involved to get the look and feel with those controls that I want (at least compared to using css)

Comment: @Logan Young - FormView allows you create any look&feel you want, just put any layout inside ItemTemplate. The benefit of usage FormView over plain controls allocation on page - that you just specify datasource and don't need to call Bind for each control with data. DetailsView little bit restricted on layout manipulation.